# How can I display an error and terminate the app when `NSURLSession` times out?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, error-handling, nsurlsession

So I'm trying to run this `NSURLSession` `dataTask` on the intranet-- however if the user isn't connected to the intranet, the request will time out.

In this case, I want to display an error for the user, and terminate the app

I currently have this:

```
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = "Network Error"
            alert.informativeText = "Make sure you are connected to the Internal Network.  Now closing..."
            alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.warning
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if alert.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
                    NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
                }
            }
        }
        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
```

But this code just crashes at the `alert.runModal()`

```
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000102b99130 swift_reportError + 129
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000102bb5b50 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 60
2    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001029a6250 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 342
3    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000102b20e90 partial apply for (_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #2) + 109
4    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001029a6250 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 342
5    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000102ad39a0 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 96
6    MyApp                         0x00000001001bf2e0 AppDelegate.(_getServiceTicket(completion : () -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) + 1063
7    MyApp                         0x00000001001c2670 thunk + 203
8    CFNetwork                          0x00007fffb00d8381 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
9    CFNetwork                          0x00007fffb00d7b0c __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 308
10   Foundation                         0x00007fffb29b2f12 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
11   Foundation                         0x00007fffb29b2b97 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
12   Foundation                         0x00007fffb29b1084 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 672
13   Foundation                         0x00007fffb29ad112 __NSOQSchedule_f + 201
14   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001032ee784 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15   libdispatch.dylib                  0x0000000103305872 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 205
16   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001032f760c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1174
17   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001032f076d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 671
18   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001032f06ab _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 114
19   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00000001033652c7 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
20   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00000001033652a8 start_wqthread + 13
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the trace from the crash report?

Comment: Posted, but because it happened in a closure, it looks like the stack trace doesn't really help much?

Comment: I had stepped through to confirm, and once it hit the `runModal` line, it crashed

Comment: I feel like my technique here kinda sucks anyways, i'm not really following any pattern, feels like I'm just throwing in a random catch and alert

Comment: You've got `reportFatalError` in there, which means that some error message has probably been logged to the Console (if you don't see it, try hitting Continue in the debugger UI). Could you post the text of that?

Comment: Also, which thread does it say it is that crashed?

Comment: ah wait I lied, upon a closer inspection, it looks like it's crashing on the last line, `let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse` . the alert window never shows up.  It's crashing on "Thread 9 Queue: NSOperationQueue ... DEFAULT (serial)"

Comment: Please check the Console for the fatal error which should get logged there, and post it.

Comment: Actually never mind, I see the problem. Please stand by while I write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the declaration for the completion handler for `dataTask()`, you will see that its three parameters, `data`, `response`, and `error`, are all optional. In the case that `error` is non-nil, it is likely that `data` and `response` will be nil, since the program was not able to contact the server in order to get any response back. Therefore, instead of this line:

```
let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
```

you should:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    // handle the response
}
```

The other option is to `guard` for the response, so that you can present a meaningful error to the user in the case that it is not present or in the correct format:

```
guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
    // handle the error
}
```

Additionally, since the case where `error` is non-nil is going to result in closure of the app, the rest of the processing in this method is probably irrelevant in that case, so it may be a good idea to stick a `return` at the end of the `if error != nil` block to exit early from it after enqueuing the alert.